# Are there any examples of artificial creoles of natural languages?

Tags: list-of-languages, typology, creoles

I remember reading somewhere of a creole-ish artificial language of two (possibly more) natural languages. In the text (I do NOT remember where it was) only one creole (I'm using the term loosely here, without regards to native speakers) was mentioned, without any usage/examples.

Are there any examples of constructed languages that are specifically designed to be creoles (again, with a very loose usage of the term creole here) of natural languages?

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, [Lang Belta](http://expanse.wikia.com/wiki/Belter_Creole), which is the constructed creole spoken on the science fiction television show *The Expanse.*

Comment: Can you provide a link please?

Comment: @Zacharý added one

Answer (score 5):

To name a few:

- [**Da Mätz se Basa**](http://www.frathwiki.com/Da_M%C3%A4tz_se_Basa): High German.
- [**Old Piscean**](http://www.frathwiki.com/Old_Piscean_language): British English.
- [**Kjā**](http://www.frathwiki.com/Gan_Language_Family): Yoruba.
- [**Cheyoon**](http://www.frathwiki.com/Cheyoon): Mandarin.
- [**Al Mastizu**](http://www.frathwiki.com/Al_Mastizu): a creole of English, Spanish and Arabic.

Comment: Al Mastizu seems most like the one I remember seeing. To bad none of these projects seem to be alive (tell me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Cheyoon appears to be alive: most recent edit was last June. Of course lack of recent webpage updates don't mean a project is dead.

Comment: Well, from ~2007 or something ... we can assume dead

Comment: Assume project death at your own risk! Just because a web article isn't updated doesn't mean the author isn't still working on it!

Answer (score 5):

More of a pidgin experiment than full fledged con-creole, but worth a mention anyway: [Viossa](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/3y2yek/viossa_an_experimental_pidgin_one_year_in_the/). Being made by conlangers, it likely has somewhat more elaborate grammar than most pidgins though (such as a morphological passive marker and a lot more adpositions than you’d find in most. Source: am co-creator).

Comment: Holy crap, that seems interesting. Originally I was looking for a Creole of two or three languages, but this is just as interesting!

Comment: I mean it *could* be a creole... all you need to do is find a young child and only speak Viossa around it!

Comment: Sorry, I meant creole-ish, in the manner of development of the language. Rather than native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

There is Lingua Franca Nova, which was named after the original Lingua Franca (yes, there really was once a language called Lingua Franca, it was used by traders in the Mediterranean I believe). But all he had to go off of was the languages it drew its (initial) vocabulary from, knowledge of how creoles develop, and two sentences in the original Lingua Franca which he had no translation to at the time. Lingua Franca Nova is so close to the original, that many think he actually replicated the original Lingua Franca, unaware that he had little to no knowledge of it at the time.